# Is it possible to write working code that uses read/write .config for ASP.Net Web Application type projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, read-write

I have been employing the content shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0) and successfully test ran it in a Console Application type project, however in attempting to adapt the code (with some modifications so as to successfully eliminate build errors) for an ASP.Net Web Application project I wind up receiving the following run-time error.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.

Source Error:

Line 24:            ShowConfig();
Line 25: 
Line 26:            System.Configuration.Configuration config =
Line 27:            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
Line 28:

Is what I am attempting even possible, or should I attempt an altogether different approach for ASP.Net Web Application projects?

Comment: You're trying to write to your own app.config from the running app? I cant think of a valid use case for this code.

Comment: likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278969/how-to-open-a-sectiongroup-in-an-asp-net-web-application

Comment: Why not just save it to the DB somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think there are probably simpler approaches, but it depends on what sort of data you are trying to store and why. You should consider these things first:

- Collision. Can two or more visitors access the web page that writes to your settings file at the same time?
- Permanency. Will the data need to persist beyond an application re-start?
- Speed. Does your application frequently require the settings data in order to keep running?

If there's no risk of collision, you could write to a file (The App_Data folder is a common location for files like this and its contents are not served up by the web server, so they remain private.) If there is a risk of collision, you need to lock the file while you are writing to it, which is more complex.

If there's no need for permanency, you can use [ASP.NET application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) This will also be fast and does provide methods for locking, but it's not permanent storage, so you lose the data if the application restarts.

You can combine both of those approaches if you need to prevent collision, provide permanent storage and give your application fast access to the data.